# Can someone explain to me that the algorithm of the password hash that use in ASP.NET CORE 6 MVC (Identity Entity Framework Core Ver 6.0.8)?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I would like to know the default encrypted algorithm use in this framework and how can I edit to make my own encrypted algorithm by adding some words before the whole password hash generated.

Comment: Hashing is not encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user207421 is absolutely correct: "Encrypting" plaintext (e.g. a password), and generating a password hash are two completely different things.

I'm not sure what you actually wish to accomplish, or why.  But besides the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-6.0), you might find these two links useful:

- https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-asp-net-core-identity-passwordhasher/
- https://andrewlock.net/migrating-passwords-in-asp-net-core-identity-with-a-custom-passwordhasher/

Per the first link:

> - ASP.NET Identity Version 2: PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA1, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 1000 iterations
> - ASP.NET Core Identity Version 3: PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA256, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 10000 iterations

A wise caveat from the second article:

> You should always think carefully before replacing security-related
> components, as a lot of effort goes into making the default components
> secure by default. This article solves a specific problem, but you
> should only use it if you need it!